# Can we use Azure AD B2C as a federated IDP with Oracle IDCS?

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Oracle IDCS for our Oracle Apps that use SAML authentication. We would like to federate the authentication to use Azure AD B2C. For this we need federation between Oracle IDCS and Azure AD B2C. Can we setup Azure AD B2C as a trusted IDP with Oracle IDCS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Refer to [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-the-componentspace-saml-2-0-stack-to-azure-ad-b2c-c6e8288eeb4b).

That post refers to the Microsoft default documentation.

As long as you have the metadata or all the relevant details you can connect any client-side SAML stack to B2C.

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is no way to accomplish ***setup Azure AD B2C as a trusted IDP with Oracle IDCS***.
According to Azure AD B2C doc.

> By acting as an identity provider (IdP) and achieving single-sign-on
> (SSO) with SAML-based service providers (your applications)

And this `your application` is an Azure Web app.
Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers#:%7E:text=Azure%20AD%20B2C%20acts%20as,ADFS%2C%20Salesforce%2C%20or%20Shibboleth.).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you sure on this - the doc doesn't explicitly mention it has to be an Azure web app.